# jquery.viewport.js plugin targeting element

Tags: jquery, viewport

I using the :viewport plugin found here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

```
        if ($('#footer tr:in-viewport')) {
            $('#title-area').css('background-color','red');
        };
```

The background color is applied but the footer only contains div elements.. ?
I quess my question is am I targeting correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
 $("a.more-results:in-viewport").each(function() {};
```

Comment: I actually had a hard time trying to figure out why a selector like yours wasn't matching an if statement. Turns out the selector `expr[':']` returns a collection of matched elements and not only `true` or `false` as one would expect. I confess I lost some time on this issue but in the end I learned one more thing about jQuery. :-) In my case I checked like this: `$("#messagewrapper:above-the-top").length > 0` instead of checking for a boolean value.